# Create chart with values from specific columns

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I have a macro that create a chart with values from column "Activation" and column "Value" (without header).
Right now, "Activation" column is A and "value" column is on E, but sometimes this positions can be different.
How can i change this macro to work from any position of "activation" and "value"?

```
    Sub CreateChart()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cht As Object

    Set find1 = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="Activation", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    CA = find1.Column 'column number for Activation
    Set find2 = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="Value", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    CV = find2.Column 'column number for Value
    Dim lastRow As Long   
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, CA).End(xlUp).Row

    'I want to change the A column with CA and the E column with CV
    Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow & ",E2:E" & lastRow)

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2  
    cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
    cht.Chart.HasTitle = False          
    cht.Chart.ChartType = xlLine
        With ActiveSheet
    .ChartObjects(1).Top = .Range("I2").Top
    .ChartObjects(1).Left = .Range("I2").Left
    .ChartObjects(1).Width = 500
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: you can use Cells(rownumber, column number) instead of range to avoid the problem of turning column numbers into letters. Does that help?

Comment: No, it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really?

```
   set rng = range("a2:" & cells(lastrow,ca).address) & ",E2:" & cells(lastrow,cv).address)
```

EDIT
       set rng = range(Cells(2,ca).address & ":" & cells(lastrow,ca).address) & "," & cells(2,cv).address & ":" & cells(lastrow,cv).address)

EDIT2 (sorry, don't have excel to check my typing)

```
set rng = range(Cells(2,ca).address & ":" & cells(lastrow,ca).address & "," & cells(2,cv).address & ":" & cells(lastrow,cv).address)
```

Comment: it must be cells(2,CA):cells(lastrow,CA) ,  cells(2,CV):cells(lastrow,CV). How can I modify the range like this?